# SwiftUI: How to sum CoreData with dynamic filters?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

In another question I have posted a solution for summary of CoreData with filters. **The problem is: I cannot make those filters dynamic.**

I have a CoreData entity: **NPTransaction** with attributes: **date (Date)** and **value (Integer 64)**.

Working code for sum with static filter:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct DashboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    // FetchRequest with predicate set to "after now" 
    @FetchRequest(entity: NPTransaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NPTransaction.value, ascending: false)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", Date() as NSDate)) var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<NPTransaction>

    // sum results using reduce
    var sum: Int64 {
        fetchRequest.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("sum")
                        Text("\(sum)")
                            .font(.largeTitle)

                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()

                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
    }

}

struct DashboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return DashboardView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Now if I try to add **selectedDate** variable like this:

```
// (...)

struct DashboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var selectedDate = Date()

    @FetchRequest(entity: NPTransaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NPTransaction.value, ascending: false)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date > %@", selectedDate as NSDate)) var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<NPTransaction>

// (...)
```

I am getting an error:

> Cannot use instance member 'selectedDate' within property initializer;
>   property initializers run before 'self' is available

So I have tried to move FetchRequest to init later in the code like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct DashboardView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var selectedDate = Date()

    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<NPTransaction>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("sum")
                        Text("\(sum)")
                            .font(.largeTitle)

                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()

                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
    }

    init() {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<NPTransaction>(entity: NPTransaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NPTransaction.value, ascending: false)
        ], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", Date() as NSDate))

        var sum: Int64 {
            fetchRequest.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
        }
    }

}
```

But now I am getting 2 errors. One on the line with reduce:

> Value of type 'FetchRequest' has no member 'reduce'

And one on the line with Text("(sum)") :

> Use of unresolved identifier 'sum'

**How to solve this problem? How to sum CoreData FetchRequest with dynamic filters that users could change?**

---

**SOLUTION**
Based on answers from Asperi and Aspid, here is the final code that made dynamic filters work with sum of CoreData values:

**DashboardView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardView: View {
    @State var selectedDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                // selectedDate change is controlled in another DateView
                DateView(selectedDate: $selectedDate)

                // selectedDate is passed to init in DashboardViewSum
                DashboardViewSum(selectedDate: selectedDate)

                Spacer()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}

struct DashboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return DashboardView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

**DashboardViewSum.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DashboardViewSum: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext   
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<NPTransaction>
    var sum: Int64 {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("sum")
                Text("\(sum)")
                    .font(.largeTitle)

            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }

    // selectedDate is passed from DashboardView and makes predicate dynamic. Each time it is changed, DashboardViewSum is reinitialized
    init(selectedDate: Date) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<NPTransaction>(entity: NPTransaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \NPTransaction.value, ascending: false)
        ], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", selectedDate as NSDate))
    }

}

struct DashboardViewSum_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        return DashboardViewSum(selectedDate: Date()).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform fetch in Init, you need to get context first. 
`@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext` does not help you, becouse its not ready yet.
`@FetchRequest` is a wrapper that allows you to do fatches when you need result, but it doesnt perferm fetch when you define it. 
This code works for me, but im not realy sure whether getting context this way is realy correct and works good in all the cases:

```
init(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContaner.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SomeType> = SomeType.fetchRequest
    //... some order and filter
    if let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest){
        //result is [someClass] - do what you need
    }
}
```

But there is an alternative. 
You can extract Sum view in subView, and pass `date` variable through `init`, where you use predicate. When you change `@State` date, subView will initialize again and fetch will perform with new date. That looks much better.

Comment: Thank you very much, Aspid! I couldn't make your code to work, but your alternative idea helped me to fix the problem. Brilliant! I have used your idea with Asperi's fix of my code and now it works :) I have edited my question to provide working solution based on your and Asperi's answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume it was meant to make `sum` as computable `DashboardView` property (out of `init`), as

```
var sum: Int64 {
    fetchRequest.wrappedValue.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }
}

...
init() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Asperi! Your code helped me got rid of errors and made me 1 step closer to solution. Aspid's idea combined with your fix made it working. I have edited my question to provide working solution based on your and Aspid's answers. Thanks!